# Function template receiving any standard map

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am writing a function that should receive one of (`std::map`, `std::multimap`, `std::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_multimap`). My code is as follow:

```
template<template <class, class> class Map, typename Coord>
    inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<Coord>::value>::type 
    filter(Map<Coord, Coord>& map, Coord step = 2) {
            for (auto it = std::begin(map); it != std::end(map);) {
                if (it->second - it->first <= step){
                    it = map.erase(it);
                }
                else
                    ++it;
            }
        }
```

The template template parameter `Map` does not generalize for all types of maps. The `std::map` and `std::multimap` receive four template parameters, and `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_multimap` receive five template parameters. This implies that I can not solve the problem with a template template parameter. Is there any way to solve this with the constraint that all maps must have `KeyType = ValeType = Coord`? I would not like to specify explicitly the parameters types in a call to `filter`.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. Compiler says that the definition of the map is ambiguous. it only works if I call the function by explicitly stating the template parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Just write your own type trait:

```
template <typename M, typename COORD>
struct is_map_of_coord : std::false_type { };
```

That you then specialize for the 5 maps:

```
template <typename COORD, typename C, typename A>
struct is_map_of_coord<std::map<COORD, COORD, C, A>, COORD>
: std::true_type { };

template <typename COORD, typename H, typename K, typename A>
struct is_map_of_coord<std::unordered_map<COORD, COORD, H, K, A>, COORD>
: std::true_type { };

etc.
```

Which lets you accept any `map`, regardless of its allocator, comparator, hash function, etc, as long as it's `Key`/`Value` are `Coord`:

```
template <typename Map, typename Coord = int>
inline typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_arithmetic<Coord>::value &&
    is_map_of_coord<Map, Coord>::value
>::type 
filter(Map& map, Coord step = 2) {
    /* body */
}
```

Or you can shorten that by just assuming that since all the maps have a `key_type` and `mapped_type`, verify that those both exist and are the same as `COORD`:

```
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename M, typename COORD, typename = void>
struct is_map_of_coord : std::false_type { };

template <typename M, typename COORD>
struct is_map_of<M, K, void_t<
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename M::key_type, COORD>::value>,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename M::mapped_type, COORD>::value>
> >
: std::true_type
{ };
```

Comment: Can not infer substitution for `Coord`, must specify explicitly.

Comment: @RaulAlonso Just have to add a default type for `Coord`, updated.

Answer (score 4):

You tagged c++11 so I would try to use variadic template parameters:

```
template<template <class ... > class Map, typename Coord, typename ... MapParms >
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<Coord>::value>::type
filter(Map<Coord, Coord, MapParms... >& map, Coord step = 2)  
{   
    for (auto it = std::begin(map); it != std::end(map);) 
    {   
        if (it->second - it->first <= step)
        {   
            it = diagram.erase(it);
        }   
        else
        {   
            ++it;
        }   
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although those template classes take a different number of arguments, they have defaults, so can all be instantiated with just two. As such, you could just use a variadic template, then anything which isn't instantiatable with two arguments will result in a compiler error anyway:

```
template<template <class...> class Map, typename Coord>
```

Comment: This assumes you don't want to support maps with a different ordering function, or different hash from the default.  Which seems strange.